# SpecRun.exe: run .feature or .playlist file from command line

Tags: testing, automated-tests, specflow, autotest, specrun

Good day. I have a several .feature files:

1.feature

2.feature

1.playlist

2.playlist

etc.

I can run they separatelly in visual studio:

-any feature file in debug mode

-any playlist with Test Explorer.

But if i need to run one of they from command line, what i should do?

If i use `SpecRun.exe` run

`SpecRun.exe run %profile%.srprofile "/baseFolder:%~dp0\bin\Debug" /log:specrun.log`

this performs launch of ALL scenarios in ALL .feature files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the command line switches of the SpecRun.exe here http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Command-Line/

You are looking for /filter to filter your execution to a single scenario. 
The format of it is documented here: http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Profiles/#Filter

Comment: This links looks like a solution, but there is no example. And if i write SpecRun.exe run filter: , what i should write after?

Comment: /filter:testpath:Feature:FileName - solution for me. Thank you!